# Call overrided method in the superclass in Love2D

Tags: lua, super, overriding, love2d

How do I call the overrided method in the superclass from the subclass in Love2D?

```
Sprite = {}
function Sprite:new(x, y, image)
    local self = {}
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.image = image

    function self:draw()
        love.graphics.draw(self.image, self.x, self.y)
    end
    return self
end

ExplorerWindow = {}
function ExplorerWindow:new(x, y, image)
    local self = Sprite:new(x, y, image)

    function self:draw()
        -- Here I want to call draw in Sprite
    end
    return self
end

function love.load()
    explorerWindow = ExplorerWindow:new(200, 200, love.graphics.newImage("res/window.png"))
end

function love.draw()
    explorerWindow:draw()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the older function in a temporary variable.

```
function ExplorerWindow:new(x, y, image)
    local self = Sprite:new(x, y, image)
    local oldDraw = self.draw

    function self:draw()
        oldDraw(self)
    end
    return self
end
```

Also, please use `setmetatable` accordingly.